# How to open Scratchpad in Firefox newest Version 81.0

Tags: firefox, scratchpad

I am not able to find the option to open the scratchpad in Firefox version 81.0.

Normally it can be opened with Shift-F4. But obviously its not working for the newest version 81.0.

Any hints ?

Comment: One simple googling away: "Scratchpad is deprecated as of Firefox 70 (bug 1565380), and will be removed as of Firefox 72 (bug 1519103). " - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Tools/Scratchpad

Comment: The linked page notes, however:  "As an alternative, starting in Firefox 71, you can use the [multi-line mode of the JavaScript console input.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Multi-line_mode)"

Answer (score 0):

In the release of Firefox 72.0 (2020-01-07) the Scratchpad feature was removed from Firefox.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/72#developer_tools

I believe there's currently (2024-03-18) no good alternative for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just open console (`Ctrl + Shift + K`) and switch to multi-line editor mode (`Ctrl + B`).

See: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/the_command_line_interpreter/index.html#Multi-line_mode